# Essential Algorithms book, clarification required

Tags: algorithm

```
Integer: FindMedian(Integer: array[]) 
For i = 0 To array.Length - 1 
// Find the number of values greater than and less than array[i]. 

Integer: num_larger = 0 
Integer: num_smaller = 0 

For j = 0 To array.Length - 1
    If (array[j] < array[i]) 
        Then num_smaller = num_smaller + 1 
    If (array[j] > array[i]) 
        Then num_larger = num_larger + 1 Next j 
    If (num_smaller = num_larger) 
        Then Return array[i] 
    End If 
Next i 
End FindMedian
```

Now about the complexity of the algoritm, the author says:

If the array contains N values, the outer For i loop executes N times. For every one of those iterations, the inner For j loop executes N times. That means the steps inside the inner loop execute N × N = N times, giving the algorithm a run time of O(N ).

I think the complexity should be O(N^2). Am I wrong?

Comment: Can you put some newlines in the code? It appears as a single line.

Comment: Sure, I am already on it. I posted using SO android app which did all the mess up.

Comment: Now it should be indented by 4 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course Order will be o(N^2) because for each outer loop your inner loop will run n time so there are n outer loop.
time complexity will be o(n^2).

Can you please share the link of book with page number on which you found it?

Comment: Book's name is right in the title of the post and chapter 3(Arrays)

Comment: If the array contains N values, the outer For i loop executes N times. For 
every one of those iterations, the inner For j loop executes N times. That means the steps inside the inner loop execute N ×N = N2 times, giving the algorithm a run time of O(N2). this lines are copied exactly from the book. book is correct but there is  printing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think it is.

From https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

`O(N^2)` represents an algorithm whose performance is directly proportional to the square of the size of the input data set. This is common with algorithms that involve nested iterations over the data set. Deeper nested iterations will result in`O(N^3)`, `O(N^4)` etc.

```
bool ContainsDuplicates(IList<string> elements)
{
    for (var outer = 0; outer < elements.Count; outer++)
    {
        for (var inner = 0; inner < elements.Count; inner++)
        {
            // Don't compare with self
            if (outer == inner) continue;

            if (elements[outer] == elements[inner]) return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Which is exactly what you are asking.